# In MeasureOverride (WPF Panel), how do I handle an infinity value in availableSize when I have no intrinsic desired size?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I found a few other questions from people dealing with subclassing Panel in WPF and implementing their own layout work, and getting Infinity or PositiveInfinity for a dimension passed to MeasureOverride in the availableSize arg. The responses are generally, "It means you can take up as much room as you want: ignore it, add up the desired sizes of all your children and return that."

In my case I'm making a control that dynamically resizes to fill available space, so there is no intrinsic notion of desired size. It just wants to use the whole availableSize.

When I built out the ControlTemplate it ended up nested within a StackPanel, and it started getting Infinity for the available height, even though the control had no scrollbar. If I just capped it at some fixed number, it would just clip against the window. I tried returning ActualHeight, but that didn't work because it's cyclical: there's no ActualHeight before I've done a full layout pass. So that was always 0.0.

At first I didn't know it was the StackPanel handing down Infinity and dug through the reference source for a while to no avail, and finally figured it out by using VisualTreeHelper to run through the parents and look at their ActualHeight and the StackPanel was the deepest one with a non-zero height. I changed it to be a DockPanel since I only need two controls in it, so that works as well as a StackPanel. And behold, DockPanel doesn't pass Infinity for the available height.

But that just feels like a workaround; I'd like to understand in more depth the philosophy behind the layout and why one of the standard containers with no scrollbar would tell me I can have as much space as I want. What's the "right" response to that?

Comment: You can't make a control fill to the available space. What is it supposed to do in a ScrollViewer?

Comment: Clearly it doesn't make sense to put a control like this in a container that provides conceptually unbounded space. But "You can't make a control to fill the available space"? That's obviously not true. Consider an app like WinDirStat... or a photo viewer that scales the image up to fill the window as you resize it.

My confusion was just that for some reason StackPanel behaves as though it has unbounded space, even though - unlike ScrollViewer or a SizeToContent Window - there's no clear reason why it should do that.

Comment: There is no clear reason why it shouldn't, either. But I do see your point.

Comment: There's absolutely a clear reason why it shouldn't: The argument is called "availableSpace" and the only meaningful notion of the "available space" for a non-scrolling container is pixels on the screen! Unless you can come up with a case where you want your controls to clip to the edge of the non-scrollable container and have a chunk not get rendered... which never seems useful (and you could opt to do by exceeding availableSpace anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

This:

> I'm making a control that dynamically resizes to fill available space,

Is a bad combination with:

> it ended up nested within a StackPanel

A control that "fills out space" should not be inside a stackpanel. What size do you think it should be?

Same for ScrollPanel of course.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my question is, why? Or, how can I know that? A StackPanel isn't scrollable - why doesn't it just start at the first of its contents, pass it the full available size for the stack panel minus margins, padding, etc., and then whatever that control doesn't use, pass the remainder to the next one?

I think it's obvious with ScrollPanel. But DockPanel, doesn't do that, it passes the constraints down. It's not conceptually clear to me why StackPanel has 'infinite' available space in its stack dimension when a DockPanel doesn't, when both can contain multiple elements along that axis.

Comment: A StackPanel is a little Tardis: bigger on the inside then on the outside. By design.

Comment: Is there... any reason why? Or is this just one of life's mysteries?

Comment: By-design usually is reason enough. Why would it limit its inside? Normally you add fixed-height items. What to do when it's full?

Comment: More specifically, StackPanel could do its layout by passing its input availableSize (minus margin and padding) to its first control, then subtracting what the first control used and passing the remainder to the second, and so on. That seems strictly superior to passing Infinity to all of them, since the reality is they're getting clipped if they go over in any case. Is there a principled reason to pass Infinity over using that strategy?

Comment: The principal reason is that you would have to pick a size. That does not follow the intention of a StackPanel. It's not a DockPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, having talked to other people offline too, here's the best of my understanding:

In the case where you want to do more sophisticated layout using a LayoutTransform or RenderTransform, thereby adding indirection between the control's measure / arrange pass and the actual pixel boundaries it appears within, the behavior of telling all stacked controls they can take up as much space as they want is reasonable because you're just trying to layout to a surface divorced from the actual clipped area on-screen.

It still feels like this falls under the category of "if you wrap a StackPanel in something scrollable..." but admittedly it's not clear what, in my suggested version, availableSize should be once you start messing with the RenderTransform for the StackPanel. (Though it's more fundamental than that; RenderTransform doesn't "play nice" with MeasureOverride by design because it's designed separate from the layout mechanism for performance... so it's still not clear this is a great argument.)

In any case, a way to get the behavior of a StackPanel where some selected item consumes the remainder not used by the other elements is to use a DockPanel, shove the fixed-size elements in StackPanels at Top or Bottom and the dynamically resizable one either on Top or Bottom or in the middle between two stacks.

I suppose if I needed multiple elements consuming available space in a proportioned way, that's what Grid is for.

But I have to say I still don't understand from a principled perspective why StackPanel passes Infinity down for its orientation direction to its children when calling MeasureOverride; I see no arguments for why you wouldn't pass the actual remaining unclaimed available size passed in by StackPanel's parent, and several arguments for why you would.